# Meaning of しやしま as sentence ender

Tags: particles, dialects

Look at this conversation from Twitter. Do you know what dialect it is?

> shohei110h: やっとdead stock手に入りました(´ω`)田舎にはなかなか無くて東京で購入しやしま
>   mao_sid: おれもど田舎だったから気持ちわかるなぁ。ありがとう。

The part I don't understand is しやしま at the end of the first sentence. What does that mean?

Comment: what makes you think it's a dialect and not a typo?

Comment: @Axioplase I can't think of what it would be a typo of...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that it's a typo of either しやした or しました.

At first glance, た looks pretty hard to mistype as ま, but on second thought, it's likely to happen on mobile phones. Considering that most Japanese mobile phones have keypads like:

> <kbd>あ</kbd><kbd>か</kbd><kbd>さ</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**た**</kbd><kbd>な</kbd><kbd>は</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**ま**</kbd><kbd>**や**</kbd><kbd>ら</kbd>

it's quite easy to mistype た, ま and や, which are arranged next to each other.

しやした can be a loosely pronounced slang for しました, or the author may be writing in the Edo dialect, either genuinely or for a comical effect (しやした is often heard in Jidaigeki/samurai dramas).